# Python3 ModuleNotFoundError when running from command line but works if I enter the shell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I think I'm missing something obvious here. I cloned [this repo](https://github.com/giulbia/baby_cry_detection), and now have this directory structure on my computer:

[image: screenshot of the directory structure. Main file being ~/baby_cry_detection/baby_cry_Detection/pc_main/train_model.py]

When I try to run `python baby_cry_detection/pc_main/train_set.py`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "baby_cry_detection/pc_main/train_set.py", line 10, in <module>
    from baby_cry_detection.pc_methods import Reader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'baby_cry_detection'
```

However, if I type `python` and enter the interactive shell and then type the command

`from baby_cry_detection.pc_methods import Reader`

it imports just fine with no error. I'm completely baffled. I'm using a virtualenv and both instances are using the same python installation, and I haven't changed directories at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) could be the reason that the module is not found when `python` command is executed. Here is how we can check if that is indeed the case:

In the `train_set.py` file, add `import sys; print(sys.path)`. Looking at the error, the path may contain `/path/to/baby_cry_detection/baby_cry_detection/pc_main`. If that is the case, then we have found the issue which is that `baby_cry_detection.pc_methods` will not be found in the directory that `sys.path` is looking into. We'll need to append the parent `baby_cry_detection` directory to `sys.path` or use relative imports. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer.

The reason that python prompt successfully imports the module could be because the prompt is started in the correct parent directory. Try changing the directory to `baby_cry_detection/pc_main/` and try importing the module.

Comment: I think you're right. The problem now is that when I try to do a relative import I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` even though I have init files up and down the directory structure. But that's another question for another day I guess.